# What happen to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn when DisplayMember is set?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

When I have a [`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.aspx) filled with binded values, and if I set the [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.displaymember.aspx) property, I get the [`DataError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror.aspx) event raised with a `FormatException`:

> DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid

If `DisplayMember` is not set, and so the view is showing the result of `.ToString()`, all work as expected.

Here is a complete example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var categories = new[] { CustomerCategory.Cat1, CustomerCategory.Cat2, CustomerCategory.Cat3 };
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dataGridView1.DataError += new DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(dataGridView1_DataError);
        this.dataGridView1.CellParsing += new DataGridViewCellParsingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellParsing);
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        {
            DataSource = categories,
            HeaderText = "Category",
            DataPropertyName = "Category",
            DisplayMember = "Name" // if we omit this line, there is not DataError event raised
        });

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = new[] 
        { 
              new Customer() { Category = CustomerCategory.Cat1 } 
            , new Customer() { Category = CustomerCategory.Cat2 } 
            , new Customer() { Category = CustomerCategory.Cat3 } 
        }.ToList();
    }

    void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        var value = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        var type = value != null ? value.GetType() : null;
        string message = "Error"
            + Environment.NewLine + " - Column : " + e.ColumnIndex
            + Environment.NewLine + " - Line  : " + e.RowIndex
            + Environment.NewLine + " - Value : " + Convert.ToString(value) + " (" + type + ")"
            + Environment.NewLine + " - Exception : " + e.Exception.Message;
        Debug.Fail(message);
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
    {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631126/how-to-bound-a-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-to-a-object
        if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        {
            var editingControl = (DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)this.dataGridView1.EditingControl;
            e.Value = editingControl.SelectedItem;
            e.ParsingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The model:

```
public class CustomerCategory
{
    public static readonly CustomerCategory Cat1 = new CustomerCategory { Name = "Cat1" };
    public static readonly CustomerCategory Cat2 = new CustomerCategory { Name = "Cat2" };
    public static readonly CustomerCategory Cat3 = new CustomerCategory { Name = "Cat3" };

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return this.Name; }
}
public class Customer { public CustomerCategory Category { get; set; } }
```

How can I specify my own `DisplayMember` without having this annoying `DataError` event raised?
The problem appears only with `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, not with a regular [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx).

Edit : After a few tests, I can say that:

```
[DisplayMember + Not ValueMember] = FAIL
[Not DisplayMember + ValueMember] = FAIL
[DisplayMember + ValueMember] = WIN
```

So my question could be rephrased as : Is there any documentation that explain precisely what will work and what won't; and how the `DisplayMember` + `ValueMember` are linked together like it seems to be?

Re-Edit :

An interesting reference: [Problems with the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.aspx)

> However, the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn doesn't work like this,
>   although it will display the ToString value if you don't set the
>   DisplayMember, something internally goes wrong when it tries to look
>   up the SelectedItem, you have to set DisplayMember to a public
>   property of your class. Even worse, the default behaviour if you don't
>   set the ValueMember property is to return the DisplayMember, there's
>   no way of getting actual item itself. The only work around is to add a
>   property to your class that returns itself and set that property to
>   the ValueMember. Of course, if your item isn't something you are able
>   to change (such as one of the framework classes) you'll have to cludge
>   together a container object that holds a reference to your item.

Is somebody have any information about the ***something internally goes wrong*** part?

Comment: What is the Exception.Message? If you use DisplayMember I think you have also to set ValueMember.

Comment: Sorry. Have you -1ed my answer? Can you please explain me the reason?

Comment: Tell me the exact point you cannot understand of: there is a 1D datasource and you don't need to refer any column (as far as there is just 1 column); if you want to refer columns, use a 2D datasource, with columns. Please, tell me what part is confusing you.

Comment: You can now delete this question (is this how you people behave, isn't it?): you have already the information (difference between 1D and 2D datasources; in case of finding problems with a DataGridView rely on a DataTable; the property name of a class cannot be considered a column (MSDN can loosy refer to properties, but, as said, truly support columns and DataGridViews)), you can go and come back whenever you will need something else.

Answer (score 1):

Following logic may help you to resolve your issue.

I think problem is in the order of code line. Assigning datasource after assign display member property may causes the error.

Change this line;

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
{
    DataSource = categories,
    HeaderText = "Category",
    DataPropertyName = "Category",
    DisplayMember = "Category" // if we omit this line, there is not DataError event raised
});
```

### TO

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.HeaderText = "Category";
col.DataSource = categories;
col.DisplayMember = "Category";
col.DataPropertyName = "Category";
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

The datasource must be assigned before DisplayMember and ValueMember.