# DataGridView ComboBox - allow typed value OR autocomplete

Tags: c#, datagridview, autocomplete, combobox, option-type

I'm developing a WinForms app in C# / VS2010.  In two places I've a requirement to bind a ComboBox to data table row items (lets call the table 'updateTable').  Users can input *any* text here.  However, to assist users, the ComboBox list is populated from a different table (lets call it 'lookupTable') with SuggestAppend offering values that *might* be used.

I have this working perfectly in a free standing combo box by setting the following values through the form designer:

- Databindings = updateTable fieldname
- Datasource =    lookupTableBindingSource
- DisplayMember = lookupTable fieldname
- ValueMember =
- AutocompleteMode = SuggestAppend
- AutoCompleteSource = ListItems
- AutoCompleteCustomSource = (Collection)
- SelectedItem = (none)
- SelectedValue = (none)

I *also* need to achieve this in a similar way through in a ComboBox on a DataGridView and can't get this to work.  What I've tried is:

Setting up these properties through the form designer:

- DataPropertyName = updateTable fieldname
- DataSource = lookupTableBindingSource
- DisplayMember = lookupTable fieldname
- Items (Collection)
- ValueMember = (none)

Through code I'm also adding:

```
    private void identitiesDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
        {
            ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)e.Control;
            ((ComboBox)e.Control).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            ((ComboBox)e.Control).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            ((ComboBox)e.Control).AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            combo.Validated -= new EventHandler(combo_Validated);
        }
    }

    void combo_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Object selectedItem = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)identitiesDataGridView.Columns[identitiesDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(col.ValueMember))
            identitiesDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = GetPropValue(selectedItem, col.ValueMember);
        else
            identitiesDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = selectedItem;
    }

    public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
    {
       if (src == null)
           return null;
       return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }

    private void identitiesDataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (identitiesDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            identitiesDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }
```

This is a) giving me errors when the form is launched because some updateTable values are not found in the lookupTable and b) not allowing me to select anything other than lookupTable values when I edit.

Any idea how I can achieve this "type what you like but here are some suggestions" effect in a datagrid?

Comment: Problem a) seems be an issue with DataGridViewComboBoxColumn... see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861381/what-happen-to-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-when-displaymember-is-set) question

Comment: @Juaith I'm pretty sure these "Value is not valid" errors occur because it's trying to populate cells from 'update Table' values which don't appear in 'lookupTable'.  I know this because if the grid displays say 10 rows 4 of which have values which don't appear in 'lookupTable'  then I'll get the error message 4 times.  I've seen a number of suggestions that I need to add these values into the 'lookupTable' but that won't work for my requirement plus it isn't necessary when I'm working with a combo box outside of a dataviewgrid.